# labelme does not open window

Tags: python, labelme

The first time I'm using labelme, I followed the steps in the repository. For installation. I continued to run the window to use, it opens and then closes.

The output I'm having in the terminal will be this.

```bash
➜ labelme
[INFO   ] __init__:get_config:70 - Loading config file from: /home/machine_linux/.labelmerc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/labelme/widgets/canvas.py", line 618, in paintEvent
    p.translate(self.offsetToCenter())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/labelme/widgets/canvas.py", line 659, in offsetToCenter
    return QtCore.QPoint(x, y)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QPoint(): too many arguments
  QPoint(int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  QPoint(QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter; did you forget to destroy it or call QPainter::end() on it?
QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter; did you forget to destroy it or call QPainter::end() on it?
QPainter::begin: Painter already active
[1]    139652 segmentation fault (core dumped)  labelme
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install:

```bash
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

Then open the labelme app again.

Comment: Thanks @edd1 . Amazing solution, in this moment execute labelme and visualize window.